# Declaring class object with PEP 8 standard in Python (pylint error)

Tags: python, pylint, pep8

I am trying to declare an object in Python.  I am using Visual Studio Code with the basic pylint setup in it.  Here is a snip of some code I have.

```
class MyLogging:
    """A class to initialize and run the logging commands using built in logging functions."""
    def __init__(self):
    etc...

my_can_logger = MyLogging()
```

Pylint keeps giving me an error that my_can_logger is named incorrectly.

> [pylint] C0103:Invalid constant name "my_can_logger"

But I don't want it to be a constant!  I want it to be an object.  Is there some rule that I am missing?  I looked at the PEP-8 styling guide, and I seem to be following their convention pretty well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your naming is fine.

Comment: @timgeb So what might be the issue?

Comment: Wild guess: do you ever use `my_can_logger` at any point after creating it? If this is the entire program, maybe the linter thinks it's a constant because you never refer to it, e.g. in order to call any of its methods.

Comment: I just hate seeing those double green underlines!  It bugs me until I fix it.. no pun intended

Comment: @Punchki  Just remember, pylint is not the boss of you.  You are the boss of pyllint.   :)

Comment: `pylint` is just checking the names against some regular expressions.  If you're willing to change the name to get rid of the error, the regexes are here: http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:c0103

Comment: @wim Yea I looked at the question that mine was marked a duplicate of (I did extensive google searching, I swear!)  Adding the # pylint: disable=invalid-name seems to do the trick.  I will make pylint do my bidding

Comment: @Punchki Check [this](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/847)

Answer (score 4):

pylint thinks it's a constant because it's a module level variable.  Just ignore pylint, it's being stupid.  Using a module level object for the logger is a common pattern in Python.

Better linters such as flake8 or pyflakes won't give you these complaints.

Comment: Fair enough.  I just hate seeing the error pop up.

Comment: Do I need to remove pylint in order to work with flake8?  Found it as an extension to VSCode